# Unable to get message to display on my page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm unable to add a message to my Visualforce page.  Am I somehow displaying the message on a different page than the one I'm showing the user?

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page controller="OLI_SplitQty2" id="thePage" tabStyle="Product2" sidebar="false">    
<!-- Style for Page Messages -->
<style>
    .Messages { color: red; font-weight: strong;}
    .StatusPicklist { }
</style>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
    // Script to provide pop-up on 'Cancel' button click
    function confirmCancel() {
        var isCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
        if (isCancel) return true;

        return false;
    }
</script>

<!-- Section Header -->
<apex:sectionHeader title="Split Products by Quantity" />

<!-- Steps for the end users -->
<!--
<h1>Notes:</h1>
<ol>
    <li>Select the Product(s) you want to split and</li>
    <li>enter a quantity to split off</li>
</ol>
-->

<!-- Form with Page Blocks and Sections -->
<apex:form >

    <!-- Page Block providing the user with Editable Table -->   
    <apex:pageBlock title="Select the Product(s) you want to split by entering a Quantity to split off and a new Line Description (optional)">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!split}" value="Split" immediate="false" rerender="true"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:messages styleClass="Messages"/>

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="editableView" title="Opportunity Product List View" columns="1" rendered="true" collapsible="false" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OLIlist1}" var="val">

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Product Name</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!val.ID}" >{!val.Product_Name__c}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!val.Quantity}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Split Qty</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!val.Split_Qty__c}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Line Description</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!val.Description}" />
                </apex:column> 

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class OLI_SplitQty2 {

    public Opportunity Opp {get; set;}
    public List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIlist1 {get; set;}    
    public List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIlist2 {get; set;}

    private Decimal qty;
    private Decimal sQty;

    public OLI_SplitQty2() {         
        getOIDQueryParameter();
        OLIlist1 = [Select  ServiceDate,
                            Discount,
                            Description,
                            ListPrice,
                            Product2Id,
                            ProductCode,
                            Quantity,
                            UnitPrice,
                            Subtotal,
                            TotalPrice,
                            Billing_Enabled__c,
                            Account__c,
                            Deliver_to_Account__c,
                            Equipment_Price__c,
                            Installation__c,
                            IsConverted__c,
                            Product_Name__c,
                            QT_Line__c,
                            Service_Address__c,
                            Service_Address_Size__c,
                            Split_Qty__c,
                            ID,
                            PricebookEntryId,
                            OpportunityId 
                    FROM    OpportunityLineItem 
                    WHERE   OpportunityId =:Opp.Id];

        OLIlist2 = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    }

    public Boolean getOIDQueryParameter(){
        Opp = new Opportunity(id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oid'));
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference split() {
        PageReference returnPage;
        try {
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli: OLIlist1) {
                sQty = oli.Split_Qty__c;
                qty = oli.Quantity;
                    if (sQty<>Null) {
                        if (math.abs(sQty) < math.abs(qty)) {
                            OpportunityLineItem o2, o3;
                            o2 = new OpportunityLineItem();
                            o3 = new OpportunityLineItem();

                            o2 = oli.clone();
                            o2.TotalPrice = Null;
                            o2.Quantity = o2.Split_Qty__c;
                            o2.Split_Qty__c = Null;
                            if (o2.QT_Line__c<>Null) o2.QT_Line__c = o2.QT_Line__c + 1;                        
                            OLIlist2.add(o2);

                            o3 = [Select Description, ID FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE ID =:oli.Id LIMIT 1];
                            oli.Description = o3.Description;
                            oli.TotalPrice = Null;
                            oli.Quantity = oli.Quantity - oli.Split_Qty__c;
                            oli.Split_Qty__c = Null;

                        } else {
    system.Debug('Got my > error');
                            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'ERROR: Quantity to split must be less than current quantity! ['+oli.Product_Name__c+' ('+oli.Quantity+')]');
                            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                            return null;                        
                        }
                    }
            }               

            update(OLIlist1);
            insert(OLIlist2);

            returnPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Opp).view();
            returnPage.setRedirect(true);
            return returnPage;

        } catch (Exception e) {           
            throw e;
        }            
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {
        PageReference returnPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Opp).view();
        returnPage.setRedirect(true);
        return returnPage;        
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `apex:pageMessage`, not `apex:message`.

Comment: I get the following error when making that change: Unsupported attribute styleclass

Comment: The difference between pageMessage and message is simply that pageMessage is pre-styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling the issue is:

```
rerender="true"
```

To my knowledge this wont work. Try wrapping your messages in an output panel and rerendering that:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="pageMessages" layout="none">
<apex:messages styleClass="Messages"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
...
<apex:commandButton action="{!split}" value="Split" immediate="false" **rerender="pageMessages"**/>
```

Comment: Thanks - removing rerender completely took care of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
       apex:page controller="OLI_SplitQty2" id="thePage" tabStyle="Product2__c" sidebar="false">
```

Custom object : Product2__c